# jclouds with GCE Cannot connect: -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY----- doesn't contain % line [-----END ]

Tags: jenkins, jclouds

Trying to use google-compute-engine provider for jclouds there appears to be a problem when putting the pem extracted from the .p12 into the credential section of my jenkins config.xml

Followed these instruction https://github.com/jclouds/jclouds-labs-google/tree/master/google-compute-engine to extract the pem file from the p12

Error is see when trying to test connection:

`Cannot connect to specified cloud, please check the identity and credentials: chars -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- HIDDEN -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY----- doesn't contain % line [-----END ]`

If I remove the "-----BEGIN RSA", jclouds correctly tells me that % doesnt contain the line -----BEGIN
but it seems to be barfing on parsing the "-----END" part

I thought It might have to do with pasting the key into the Credential section of the configure jenkins U/I,
but I placed the key directly into the config.xml's  section, and I'm getting the same error.

jenkins-1.583-1.1.noarch with Jclouds plugin 2.8

Any ideas?

-Aric

Answer (score 0):

Convert the p12 file into pem format (it will ask for the keystore password, which is usually "notasecret"):

```
 openssl pkcs12 -in my_keystore.p12 -out my_keystore.pem -nodes
```

2. Extract only the pk and remove passphrase

   openssl rsa -in my_keystore.pem -out my_key.pem

Then you can use this key and problem will be solved.

Comment: Hi, I extracted the key properly, but when I paste it in to the credentials section the new lines get eaten and I get the error above.

Comment: by adding \n to the end of each line? did you have to do this?

Comment: I didn't have to do that. Once I follow the above steps I got the key with \n added

Comment: @Aric Did you manage to solve this? I too am also having this issue

Answer (score 0):

The solution on my side is to use the Textarea. FYI: [JENKINS-25283](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-25283)
and reason is losing the new line character. Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem after reading the key from a user interface.

The fix for me was:

```
privatekey = privatekey.replace("\\\n", System.lineSeparator());
```

This ensures the key includes system specific line-break characters.